# Flatten broken horizontal bar chart to line graph or heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have data for all the time I've spent coding. This data is represented as a dictionary where the key is the date and the value is a list of tuples containing the time I started a coding session and how long the coding session lasted.

I have successfully plotted this on a [broken_barh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh) using the below code, where the y-axis is the date, the x-axis is the time in that day and each broken bar is an individual session.

```
for i,subSessions in enumerate(sessions.values()):
    plt.broken_barh(subSessions, (i,1))
months = {}
start = getStartMonth()
for month in period_range(start=start,end=datetime.today(),freq="M"):
    month = str(month)
    months[month] = (datetime.strptime(month,'%Y-%m')-start).days
plt.yticks(list(months.values()),months.keys())
plt.xticks(range(0,24*3600,3600),[str(i)+":00" for i in range(24)],rotation=45)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: Broken bar chart produced by the above code]

I want to use this data to discover what times of the day I spend the most time coding, but it isn't very clear from the above chart so I'd like to display it as a line graph or heatmap where the y-axis is the number of days I spent coding at the time on the x-axis (or, in other words, how many sessions are present in that column of the above chart). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use sampling. Choose how many samples you want to take in a given interval (the precision, for example 288 samples per day) and split each interval by that number of samples and count how many sessions are within this sample. The downside to this is that it can't be 100% precise and increasing the precision increases the time it takes to generate (for me, it takes several minutes to generate a second-precise image, though this level of precision makes little to no difference to the result).

Here is some code which can produce both a heatmap and a line graph

```
# Configuration options
precisionPerDay = 288
timeTicksPerDay = 24
timeTickRotation = 60
timeTickFontSize = 6
heatmap = True

# Constants
hoursInDay = 24
secondsInHour = 3600
secondsInDay = hoursInDay*secondsInHour
xInterval = secondsInDay/precisionPerDay
timeTickSecondInterval = precisionPerDay/timeTicksPerDay
timeTickHourInterval = hoursInDay/timeTicksPerDay

# Calculating x-axis (time) ticks
xAxis = range(precisionPerDay)
timeTickLabels = []
timeTickLocations = []
for timeTick in range(timeTicksPerDay):
    timeTickLocations.append(int(timeTick*timeTickSecondInterval))
    hours = timeTick/timeTicksPerDay*hoursInDay
    hour = int(hours)
    minute = int((hours-hour)*60)
    timeTickLabels.append(f"{hour:02d}:{minute:02d}")

# Calculating y-axis (height)
heights = []
for dayX in xAxis:
    rangeStart = dayX*xInterval
    rangeEnd = rangeStart+xInterval
    y = 0
    for date,sessions in sessions.items():
        for session in sessions:
            if session[0] < rangeEnd and session[0]+session[1] > rangeStart:
                y += 1
    heights.append(y)

# Plotting data
if heatmap:
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow([heights], aspect="auto")
else:
    plt.plot(xAxis,heights)
    plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlim(xmin=0,xmax=len(heights))
plt.xlabel("Time of day")
plt.ylabel("How often I've coded at that time")
plt.xticks(timeTickLocations,timeTickLabels,
           fontsize=timeTickFontSize,rotation=timeTickRotation)
plt.show()
```

And here are some sample results

Graph produced by same configuration options shown in above code
[image: Graph produced by same configuration options shown in above code]

Same data but as a line graph with a lower precision (24 per day) and more time ticks (48)
[image: Same data but as a line graph with a lower precision (24 per day) and more time ticks (48)]

Comment: This proves as an example of what I'm looking for, but I'd prefer a method which is 100% precise and generates quicker. If such a method is provided as an answer, I'll accept that, otherwise this will be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find some great examples of how to create a heatmap from [matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Here is a basic code with some random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index_labels = np.arange(0,24)
column_labels = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', end='1/31/2022').strftime('%m/%d')

#random data
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.random.randint(0,60, size=(len(index_labels), len(column_labels)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=column_labels, index=index_labels)

#heatmap function
def heatmap(df, ax, cbarlabel="", cmap="Greens", label_num_dec_place=0):
    df = df.copy()
    
    # Ploting a blank heatmap
    im = ax.imshow(df.values, cmap)

    # create a customized colorbar
    cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, fraction=0.05, extend='both', extendfrac=0.05)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbarlabel, rotation=-90, va="bottom", fontsize=14)

    # Setting ticks
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(df.shape[1]), labels=df.columns, fontsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(df.shape[0]), labels=list(df.index), fontsize=12)

    # proper placement of ticks
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', top=True, bottom=False,
                   labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)

    ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(which="both", visible="False", color="white", linestyle='solid', linewidth=2)
    ax.grid(False)
    
    # Rotation of tick labels
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-60, 
             ha="right", rotation_mode=None)
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=30)

#plotting and saving
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor=(1,1,1), figsize=(20,8), dpi=200)
heatmap(df=df, ax=ax, cbarlabel="time (min)", cmap="Greens", label_num_dec_place=0)
plt.savefig('time_heatmap.png', 
            bbox_inches='tight', 
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), 
            transparent=True,
           )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the problem isn't plotting the data, it's obtaining the data in the first place. Also, my problem would require a 1-dimensional heatmap since the y-axis would be demonstrated through the color.